# Installing Caffe without CUDA: fatal error: cublas_v2.h No such file (Fedora23)

Tags: caffe

I try to install caffe under Fedora23 following these instructions [enter link description here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html). And I uncommented the `CPU_ONLY := 1` in the Makefile.config file, to install caffe without CUDA. I installed the dependencies including protobuf. However, I get the following error:

```
>make all
CXX src/caffe/layer.cpp
In file included from ./include/caffe/common.hpp:19:0,
                 from ./include/caffe/blob.hpp:8,
                 from ./include/caffe/layer.hpp:8,
                 from src/caffe/layer.cpp:2:
./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp:34:23: fatal error: cublas_v2.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:563: recipe for target '.build_release/src/caffe/layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/src/caffe/layer.o] Error 1
```

As I understand this is a CUDA related error, but I want to install Caffe without CUDA. Do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Do a 'make clean' and try again

Comment: Nope, that did not work.

Answer (score 5):

In ./include/caffe/util/device_alternate.hpp

```
line  4: #ifdef CPU_ONLY
line 32: #else
line 34: #include <cublas_v2.h>
line 99: #endif
```

If CPU_ONLY flag was enabled, the else condition shouldn't have worked.

Make sure that you are editing the Makefile.config instead of Makefile.config.example file.

Try debugging by editing this part of the code to get an idea on what is happening during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and searched for hours only to realize I had to be more careful during installation!
First thing to uncomment CPU_ONLY := 1 in Makefile.config and not Makefile.config.example. This file is in the directory where you git cloned caffe.
Second is to change cmake options. After adding OpenBLAS libraries to .bashrc and sourcing it, execute the following -

```
cd /../../src/caffe //where you have git cloned
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D CPU_ONLY=ON ..
cd ..
sudo make clean
sudo make all -j2
sudo make install -j2
sudo make runtest -j2
```

Third step is to define CPU_ONLY=1 in your header folder. I use Qt (v5.7) and I add this in the .pro file

```
DEFINES += CPU_ONLY=1
```

Caffe libraries and your code may not know if CPU_ONLY flag is defined or not when your code is compiled. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to uncomment `CPU_ONLY := 1` in your Makefile.config file before you compile the make all.
hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here I put the final solution:

- Step1: Run find

```
find /usr/local/ -name cublas_v2.h
```

And we find the path of the file:

/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/include/cublas_v2.h

- Step2: export the path

```
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/include/
```

OK! Problem solved.

`export` command can only work once. To make it a permanent change, you need to modify the ~/.bashrc:

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add

```
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/include/
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Nvidia TX1 and met this problem.
I solve by this instruction:

```
  export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-7.0/targets/armv7-linux-gnueabihf/include/
```

You can change the directory to try it.

Hope it works.

Sam

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to Anoop's answer, this is what worked for me:

- MacOS 10.12 Sierra, no CUDA, CPU_ONLY
- add `#define CPU_ONLY` to top of `device_alternate.hpp`
- This will enforce the program to go with `#ifdef CPU_ONLY` and thus will not raise the `cublas_v2.h` error.

That said, when I did this, the next error I got was

```
caffe/build$ make
.
.
.
build/install/include/caffe/util/mkl_alternate.hpp:14:10: fatal error: 'cblas.h' file not found
#include <cblas.h>
```

which I fixed with adding `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/openblas/include` to my `cmake` command.

But then the new error I got was

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target ../caffe/build/lib/libcaffe.so', needed by `libdeeplcd.dylib'.
```

And so the adventure continues...!

Comment: Also for those interested in the issues I resolved via `make` compilation instead of `cmake` compilation, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544356/install-caffe-on-mac-error-fatal-error-cblas-h-file-not-found/53899739#53899739